# Why isn't my file watcher triggering?

Tags: javascript, compilation, typescript, webstorm

I've set up my file watcher to compile my TypeScript to JavaScript. It has worked, but if I change a file it doesn't compiles again. I'm messing already for 2 hours with this problem. You can see my file watcher settings in the screen provided.

[My settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGZcE.png)

Comment: issn't the watcher triggered at all, regardless of a file you try to modify? Try setting 'show console' to 'always' - just to see if anything is happening. I'd also suggest invalidating caches 9File/invalidate caches) - may be, virtual file system has become broken

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "immediate file synchronization". Now it should compile only when you explicitly "Save all" files.

Probably was getting stuck in a compile loop when you save a file.

Comment: Can you see the compile status in a status bar when its compiling?

Comment: I don't remember that. I fixed it now. I would like to post the answer here, but I have no idea how I've fixed it.